# How to get a value from a combobox c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox, checkbox

I'm a little new to C#, so bear with me on this one...

Okay, so you right click a comboBox, select edit items, and you can add strings to the comboBox. My question is, how can I set a value to those strings? I want to use an 'if' statement to state whether a certain string is currently selected.

So I have 5 comboBoxes. When a checkbox is checked, all of them will say 'Full'. If one of those values is changed to something else, then I want a different checkbox to be checked. But since the strings in the comboBoxes have no values, I can't figure out how to use them.

To reiterate, how can I set values to the strings in the comboBoxes so I can use them in 'if' statements.

Edit: This is a Windows Form.

Comment: Is this in Windows Forms, WPF, something else?

Comment: do you mean you want a value associated with each string/label in the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check text the `Text` property.

Assuming your ComboBox is in cmb[5], and your check box is chk:

```
private ComboBox[] cmb;

private void init()
{
    cmb = new ComboBox[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ComboBox c = new ComboBox();
        Controls.Add(c);
        // TODO: Populate c with the relevant data
        c.TextChanged += new EventHandler(c_TextChanged);
    }
    chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);
}

void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ComboBox c in cmb)
        c.Text = "Full";
}

void c_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ComboBox c in cmb)
    {
        if (c.Text != "Full") return;
    }
    chk.Checked = false;
}
```

Alternatively, init could be:

```
private void init()
{
    cmb = new ComboBox[5];
    cmb[0] = comboBox1;
    cmb[1] = comboBox2;
    cmb[2] = comboBox3;
    cmb[3] = comboBox4;
    cmb[4] = comboBox5;
    foreach (ComboBox c in cmb)
        c.TextChanged += new EventHandler(c_TextChanged);
    chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);
}
```

Comment: I like the way you did it, but you need a public definition for GetEnumerator.

Comment: @cursedfungus, I don't see how a `GetEnumerator` is needed? In case there was some misunderstanding, I've added the declaration for cmb in my answer. It's really just an array of combo box.

Comment: Honestly, I don't either. The error I was getting was for the 'foreach' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most simple way:

```
Combobox.Items.Add("New string");
```

The more complex way is to create an array or list of strings and add them all at once as a Datasource:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
Combobox.Datasource = listOfStrings;
```

No matter what way you choose, you will edit the collection of ComboBox Items.

PS That's for Winforms.

Comment: Here's kinda the basic layout of what I'm looking for. checkbox1 will change all comboboxes to "Full." so if comboboxes 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 all say full, checkbox1 is checked. If I change one of those values to "Empty" then I want checkbox1 to uncheck and checkbox2 to check.